# how to assign value to the pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, say one column is:

```
{'university':'A','B','A','C'}
```

I want to change the column into:

```
{'university':1,2,1,3}
```

According to an imaginary dict:

```
{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
```

how to get this done?

ps: I solved the original problem, it's something about my own computer setting.
And I changed the question accordingly to be more helpful.

Comment: You should always post the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` - `d`:

```
df.university = df.university.map(d)
```

If need encode the object as an enumerated type or categorical variable use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html):

```
df.university = pd.factorize(df.university)[0] + 1
```

Sample:

```
d = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
df = pd.DataFrame({'university':['A','B','A','C']})
df['a'] = df.university.map(d)
df['b'] = pd.factorize(df.university)[0] + 1
print (df)
  university  a  b
0          A  1  1
1          B  2  2
2          A  1  1
3          C  3  3
```

I try rewrite your function:

```
def given_value(column):
    columnlist=column.drop_duplicates()
    #reset to default monotonic increasing (0,1,2, ...)
    columnlist = columnlist.reset_index(drop=True)
    #print (columnlist)
    #swap index and values to new Series columnlist_rev
    columnlist_rev= pd.Series(columnlist.index, index=columnlist.values)
    #map by columnlist_rev  
    column=column.map(columnlist_rev)

    return column

print (given_value(df.university))
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
Name: university, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it really solved my problem. But I still want to know what's wrong in my function.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: `columnlist_rev` is typo?

Comment: No I think, it reverse the key and value in the column.

Comment: Exactly, variable `column` is `Series`, (columns of `Dataframe`). Thank you for accepting.

Comment: Thank you for your time. And with your 'factorize' I also found some great materials and websites in data analysis to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'`

Your answer is written in the Exception statement! DataFrame object doesn't have an attribute called `column`, which means you can't call on DataFrame.column at any point in your code. I believe your problem exists outside of what you have posted here, likely to be somewhere near the part where you imported the data as a DataFrame fro the first time. My guess is that when you were naming the columns, you did something like `df.column = [university]` instead of `df.columns = [university]`. The s matters. If you read the Traceback closely, you'll be able to figure out precisely which line is throwing the error.

Also, in your posted function, you do not need the parameter df as it is not used at any point during the process.